# How to use crontab (Gentoo)?

Tags: linux, cron, gentoo

First I installed and ran `crontab`:

```
emerge cron
crontab -e
```

In another console, I ran `man cron`, but this has no examples of how to use `crontab`. Where can I get examples, and why are there none in the man page?

Comment: gentoo xi # apropos crontab
crontab: nothing appropriate

Answer (score 4):

Try reading `man 5 crontab` (which is probably a different page than you got by reading `man crontab`). `man crontab` likely directed you to a page about the crontab *executable* rather than the crontab *file*. The number 5 says to use category 5, "files, file formats, and conventions", rather than the default category (likely category 1, "general commands").

You can see all available sections for a command by using `apropos` like so:

```
$ apropos crontab
crontab (1)          - maintain crontab files for individual users (Vixie Cron)
crontab (5)          - tables for driving cron
```

There are also some examples on the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab#Examples).

Comment: Good explanation, I always forget about `aprapos`!